# Outputting text boxes to text file doesn't include CR

Tags: c#

I've got a problem whereby I've created an application where the user enters text into various text boxes. They then click a button which outputs it all into a text log file in a specific format.

I create a string which I output to a file and that string is compiled from various pieces of text and the contents of various form elements.

When it outputs, each separate line which has been created as part of the string creation outputs with CR LF (\r\n) which is how I want it, but any text which was entered into a Rich Text Box outputs with only LF (\n)

Code goes like:

```
string[] lines = {

     @"HEADER TEXT HERE",
     @"-----------------------------------------------",
     Text_Box.Text,
     Rich_Text_Box.Text,
```

........

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"\\basedirectory\" + project_name_tb.Text + @"\" + strDate);

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"\\basedirectory\" + project_name_tb.Text + @"\" + strDate
+ @"\" + strDate + @"_" + project_name_tb.Text + @"_"
+ session_number_mtb.Text + @".txt", lines);
```

The rich text boxes are multiline.

How do I make the rich text box output CR LF?

Answer (score 2):

You could try replacing all instances of LF with CRLF:

```
Rich_Text_Box.Text.Replace("\n", "\r\n")
```

Comment: Just be careful with that one - if there is already a "\r\n" then it will become "\r\r\n"

Comment: @LordWilmore I'm usually doing something like this: `.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", "\r\n")`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem even it's safe if it's already \r\n it won't replace it.

```
    public string ReplaceRichTextBoxContent(string data)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(data, "(?<!\r)\n", "\r\n");
    }
```

use it like

```
string[] lines = {

 @"HEADER TEXT HERE",
 @"-----------------------------------------------",
 Text_Box.Text,
 ReplaceRichTextBoxContent(Rich_Text_Box.Text),
```